# Is there a way to create a heatmap in R where each column gets its own scale?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, heatmap

I am trying to make a heatmap where each column has it own scale from a matrix, so that the colors in each column are unaffected by the values of other columns. 
However, as far as I can tell, none of the major packages offers an option that allows me to do this.

I am working with this matrix right now:

```
structure(c(37525.6, 38150.7777777778, 54772.3, 76581.6, 89016.8888888889, 
132229.2, 47912.2222222222, 57342.2, 61666.6, 2071694.44444444, 
4640000, 3397239.5, 310529.6, 433809.7, 437263.8, 23828.1, 33041.3, 
47197.3, 19970.4, 11566.4, 14479.1), .Dim = c(3L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("Nor", "Plac", "Vaso"), c("Tnf", "Il6", "IL8", "IP10", 
    "MCP1", "GCSF", "IL10")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`heatmap(as.matrix(data), scale = "column")`

or if you prefer the nicer looking:

```
library(dplyr)
data%>%
as.matrix()%>%
heatmap(scale = "column")
```

`scale = "column"` is built within `heatmap()` to understand to color by column.